# How to use multiple AWS Code Artifacts packages in one project

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-codeartifact

I'm working with AWS CodeArtifact and am trying to download 3 packages from the same domain but it looks like I'm required to have 3 registries in my .npmrc file rather then one that can find all in doing so 2 out of the 3 registries can not be found does anyone have any idea how to fix that? Any solution I have tried works for a few days and then breaks again with atleast one of the 3 artifacts install.

example:

```
#.npmrc file

# registry one
registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/=true"
@company/:registry=... #for package 1
@company/package_2:registry=...
@company/package_3:registry=...
```

```
# npm i
404 package 2 not found using package_1 registry link
```

the reason I'm doing package one like that is because otherwise, it can't find package one

I have looked around for this and have seen no docs or examples of people using multiple artifacts in one project. Any help would be much appreciated on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out

So AWS code Artifact has repositories for scalability and each repo has its own login credentials but each repo can contain an infinite amount of packages... think of repos as a registry instead of a repo. so you just have to add all packages under the same repository and then use one login to the artifact repo and it will find all packages you need under that repo.

example:

#.npmrc file

```
# registry one
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@company:registry=...
```

output:

```
...
added 2241 packages from 1402 contributors in 11.01s
```